# best way to locate a color changing button

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyautogui

The code I currently have is:

```
import pyautogui

location_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Button.png')
x, y = pyautogui.center(location_button)
pyautogui.click(x, y)
```

The code tries to find a exact image of Button.png on the screen, get the coordinate, and click the coordinate.

The problem is that the Button changes color gradually, so sometimes location_button returns `None`. What is the best way to get a positive match all the time even if the button color changes?

Greyscale doesn't because there are particles flying around sometimes get in the Button.

Would binary image work?

Thanks

Comment: You need to explain what constitutes a "positive match" when the color is changing -- this would mean that there is *not* an "exact image", and `None` is the correct response.

Comment: Seems like the particles should also cause a failure even if the button doesn't change color.

Comment: @Prune The positive match would be that it would be able to recognize the image on the screen even if the button's color change

Comment: Binary image can work, if you change the threshold accordingly, can you upload some sample images to give us an idea as to what it actually looks like? Sample images would help in formulating a better solution.

Comment: add sample images. Typically you can try things like trained classifier detection, template matching an various other things, it really depends on your kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

Create image files for all the different button colors, named `Button0.png`, `Button1.png`, etc., and search for them in a loop.

```
for i in range(button_image_count):
    location_button = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('Button%d.png' % 10)
    if location_button:
        break
```